# Can I deploy GA userTimingHit on Adobe DTM?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, timing

I setup userTimingHit for Google Analytics for tracking how much time spent a user on a specific page and form.
I have used JavaScript for to collect variables and send them to specific GA timing tag on Tag Manager.

Could I set it on Adobe DTM.? Anyone with experience with it?

Maybe set dataElement with specific variable? 
I tried with function and doesn’t work.

Thanks for any clues.

Comment: Can you install this plugin and provide more details as to what's not working? https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna?hl=en

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related